# Is there a name for this idiom?

Tags: go, idioms

Is there a name for this idiom where a function is chosen based on type of interface ?

```
type encoderFunc func(e *encodeState, v reflect.Value, opts encOpts)

var encoderCache struct {
    m map[reflect.Type]encoderFunc
}

func (e *encodeState) marshal(v interface{}, opts encOpts) (err error) {
    v := refect.ValueOf(v)
    valueEncoder(v)(e, v, opts)
    return nil
}

func valueEncoder(v reflect.Value) encoderFunc {
     return encoderCache.m[v.Type()]
}
```

Copied from [encoding/json](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go) and slightly altered for demonstration.

Comment: I don't know Go, but this strikes me as kind-of sort-of inheritance. If the function was part of a ABC instead of an interface, the language would automatically pick the correct method based on its type.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, which function do you mean ? I don't think this is in any way related to inheritance. The types  involved are completely unrelated.

Comment: Nvm, I think I misread the code. From description at the top and then code, it seemed like you were dispatching a function based on the type of an object.

Comment: A function is indeed being 'dispatched' based on type of object but the types are completely unrelated to one another. With inheritance (perhaps polymorphism), the function being called depends on the type of object - but the objects are all of a certain parent type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call this *dynamic method dispatch*. More or less the same mechanism used in Go interface implementation where `map[reflect.Type]encoderFunc` called [i-table](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces). One even can rewrite marshalling just with interfaces, except we can't write methods for builtin types.

```
type encodable interface{
    encode(e *encodeState, opts encOpts)
}
func (st SomeType) encode(e *encodeState, opts encOpts){
...
}
...
func (ot OtherType) encode(e *encodeState, opts encOpts){
...
}
func (e *encodeState) marshal(v encodable, opts encOpts) (err error) {
    v.encode(e, opts)
    return nil
}
```